# Google Maps API - Show Infowindow while clicking on marker in Street View

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow, google-street-view

When I click on the map marker in the regular map the info window pops up.
However it doesn't work in Street View. [JsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/6fryxprh/71/)

There seems to be an [existing issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/35828818)
I am wondering if anybody has found any alternatives.

**My javascript code**

```js
// This example displays a marker at the center of Australia.
// When the user clicks the marker, an info window opens.
function initMap() {
    var address = '204 Deer Valley Rd, Lumsden No. 189, SK S0G';
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {

        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
        zoom: 16
    });

    var defaultStreetViewPanorama = map.getStreetView();

    var contentString = '<div id="content">' +
        '<div id="siteNotice">' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div id="bodyContent">' +
        '<p><b>Uluru</b></p>' +
        '</div>' +
        '</div>';

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var infowindowSV = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: contentString
    });
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    geocoder.geocode({
            'address': address
        },
        function(results, status) {
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                });
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                    infowindow.open(defaultStreetViewPanorama, marker);
                });

                map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Imported javascript snippet

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about this issue. The code posted there doesn't work at all and I don't want to debug that.

Having a marker in the Street View panorama with an InfoWindow is no issue though.

```js
var map;

function initialize() {

  var panoPos = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2400896,121.4908558);
  var markerPos = new google.maps.LatLng(31.2400896,121.4909558);

  var panoOptions = {
    position: panoPos
  };

  var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(
    document.getElementById('map-canvas'), panoOptions);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: markerPos,
    map: panorama
  });

  var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: 'hello world'
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(panorama, marker);
  });

  panorama.setPov({
    heading: 90,
    pitch: 0,
    zoom: 0
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map-canvas {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I do have to give some credit to MrUpsidown. I did know that I could get info window working in the streetview panarama option but it wasn't working the old way. Turns out we can semi force the creation of the infowindow in streetview and it still can open and close the infowindow modal inside it.

```
  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function()       {
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    content: contentString
    }).open(map);
    new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    position: results[0].geometry.location,
    content: contentString
    }).open(map.getStreetView());
  });
```